# explicitly casting generics in C# 4

Tags: c#

Can anyone help  me in casting generic collection in c# 4.

Here is the code snippet.

GridView1.DataSource = dataServiceColl.Select(t => t.product_desc="EdibileItem")

It is throwing up runtime error at the below line,

Gridview1.Databind();

Saying it is a HTTP Exception.

I think it should be a simple type cast.

Thanks,
Kris.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
t => t.product_desc=="EdibileItem"
```

Comment: A field or property with the name 'product_desc' was not found on the selected data source. This is the error It is throwing up in Visual studio 2010 with C#. This is related to querying the data - WebServices in .Net

Comment: @kris: so you solved your problem or not ?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Exception? That has nothing to do with casting.

More importantly, why are you assigning `"EdibleItem"` to `t.product_desc` here?

```
Select(t => t.product_desc="EdibileItem")
```

Did you meant `==` instead of `=`? If so, would a `Where` be more appropriate than a `Select`?

I think it all boils down to: what are you trying to achieve, exactly?